# What is Response in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, response

I was reading four.laravel.com Documentations and I found a topic named Views & Responses.
like always, Laravel has a very limited description.

my question is not in connection with PHP Laravel Framework maybe.
I tried to google "What is Response" but there was not a good resources or may be my search keywords was wrong. but...
**What is a Response? What does it do? When can it be used inside my projects.**

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In essence, [Reponse](http://laravel.com/docs/responses) in Laravel is HTTP Response object you are sending back to your visitor's browser, after the visitor(client browser) send a [Request](http://laravel.com/docs/requests) to one of your Routes.

Generally you won't be creating the basic Reponse object (using `Response::make()`) unless you need to explicitly set some details of the response yourself (such as setting Response Header, status code).

Rather, much of the Response you will be sending to the client will come from the `View::make()` which implements [RenderableInterface](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Support.Contracts.RenderableInterface.html). Your view content is wrapped inside Response object with the correct header and sent to the client.

Or you will be using `Redirect::to` (or its variant) to redirect to other Routes: this will create a [RedirectResponse](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Http.RedirectResponse.html) object which is also a type Response object. In case of [Redirect](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Routing.Redirector.html), it will automatically set the header Status Code to 302 (this tells your client browser that it is a redirect) so you really don't have to create your own RedirectResponse object and go through all the trouble of setting the Response header.

The easy way to think about it is, whatever you are sending back to the client is wrapped in the Response object and Laravel is providing you with some functionality to access (or make) the Response object itself.

Hope this helps.